# Wrong plot when using the not simplified network in Osmnx

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

Using Osmnx, I am plotting a network formed by two districts, when I use `simplify = True` both districts appear. However when I use `simplify = False` only one district appears (I need to use the network that is not simplified). Does anyone know why?

**Here is the code:**

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import osmnx as ox
import pandas as pd
from shapely.wkt import loads as load_wkt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)
import matplotlib as mpl
import random as rd


distrito = ['Setúbal District','Lisbon District']
G = ox.graph_from_place(distrito, network_type='all_private', simplify=False)

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G)
```

When using **`simplify = True`** i get this image:

[image]

When I use **`simplify = False`** I get this one:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: the boundaries of Setúbal and Lisbon are not contiguous. There's a gap between them at the mouth of the Tagus River. This gap is spanned by the 25 de Abril bridge. If you use `retain_all=True`, your results should be approximately the same between your two methods.

The longer answer is: when `simplify=True` you remove interstitial nodes along an edge to retain nodes only at true intersections and dead-ends. This simplification allows the 25 de Abril bridge to span across your two discontiguous boundaries (Setúbal and Lisbon) as a single edge. Thus it is not removed, even though it lies outside your requested boundaries. When `simplify=False`, you get a disconnected graph (since the bridge linking the two components is not retained, due to all the nodes outside your requested boundaries), resulting in all but the largest connected graph component being dropped when you use the default parameterization of `retain_all=False`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!! I will do as you advise and use retain_all=True.

I look forward to hearing from you again regarding the conclusion of your investigation. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: Since there is no connection between the boundaries when using simplify=False, I can't calculate how long it takes to travel from a node in one boundary to a node in the other. Do you have any suggestion on How I could go on and do this? I could get more boundaries and go around but the result I would obtain would not be correct since I would be taking the longest route by not passing through the bridge.

Comment: You can buffer your boundaries using the `buffer_dist` argument: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.graph.graph_from_place